# Discrepancy in gem version between "gem list" and Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile

When I type

```
  gem list
```

I see

```
 some_gem (1.18)
```

But when I check Gemfile.lock, I see

```
/Gemfile.lock

some_gem (1.23)
```

Can any explain this discrepancy? Is the gem version in the Gemfile.lock the authoritative version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote the following from [GemBunlder.com](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/rationale.html) that the `Gemfile.lock`

> The Gemfile.lock makes your application a single package of both your own code and the third-party code it ran the last time you know for sure that everything worked.

Further to this it also states that when you run the `bundle install` command bundler will install gems on your system repository which are shown in your `gem list`. Also you can run the following command `gem list -r some_Gem` what this will do is check your remotely other avaliable versions for `some_gem`. Also another command that would be useful to use is the `bundle exec bundle cleanup`.

**Update**

If my explanation wasn't clear enough for you the purpose of doing `gem list` will detail all the gem on your system. Whereas the gem version in the `Gemfile.lock` is the version used in your app. In your case the version being used `some_gem(1.2.3)`. BUT! the version that was installed on your `system` was `some_gem(1.18)` Hope this clarifies things

Comment: Hey thanks for responding David.  I also read the quote as well but I still don't know the answer to my question.  Am I using the gem's version 1.18 or 1.23 for my app?

Comment: @User314159 see update explanation. In short the version being used in your app is `some_gem(1.23)`